# Reflected Property GetValue() Throwing NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, system.reflection, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm trying to get the value of the "SelectedText" property for a control using reflection.  The control type is a DevExpress MaskBox.  When I debug and look at the "SelectedText" property, it shows the value that I want to retrieve (e.g. "some text" in the picture below).  However, there is another line showing that the MaskBox has not implemented the "SelectedText" property and that the property is a member of the base type (System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase).

How do I retrieve the "SelectedText" property from the control without throwing NotImplementedException?

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C) && ActiveControl.ContainsFocus)
    {
        bool isLayoutControl = (ActiveControl.GetType() == typeof(LayoutControl)); //devex layoutcontrol is a container so... it will return as the active control even if a textbox in the layout is selected

        if (isLayoutControl)
        {
            LayoutControl layout = (LayoutControl)ActiveControl;
            Control activeControl = layout.ActiveControl;
            Type activeControlType = activeControl.GetType();
            PropertyInfo pi = activeControlType.GetProperty("SelectedText");
            var baseVal = pi.GetValue(activeControl); //throws not implemented exeption here
        }
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

You can see here that the "SelectedText" property is shown while debugging with the correct value "some text"

[image]

Comment: Did you notice that the `SelectedText` that has a value is defined in `TextBoxBase`? That control defined its own property by the same name with the `new` keyword to shadow it rather than override it. Why are you using reflection? `((TextBoxBase)activeControl).SelectedText` should get you what you need.

Comment: Judged by your debug window screenshot these properties seem to be implemented really twice on that control: Once by the base class TextBoxBase; once by the DevExpress MaskBox itself. And the latter implementation just seems to throw the NotImplementedException - at this stage.
Probably you need to cast the object "down" to TextBoxBase to get the functional implementation.

Comment: @madreflection: I did notice the TextBoxBase but, wasn't sure how to access it.  Your solution works perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: Yikes... it occurs to me that they were trying to prevent consumers from using those properties. That's a *really nasty* case of the Circle-Ellipse problem. That is to say that `TextBoxBase` is not really an appropriate base class if its members don't make sense in the derived class.

Comment: As for reflection: when a member is shadowed like that, you need to go down to the class where the shadowed member is defined -- `typeof(TextBoxBase)` -- and then find that member and invoke it. `GetType()` was returning `typeof(MaskBox)`, which gave you the shadowing property that threw the exception.